# Sentence confusion

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, subjunctives

Is it okay to write this:

> Her condition was that he should not be allowed into her house.

Or, is the grammatical format this:

> Her condition was that he not be allowed into her house.

Comment: Either is acceptable.

Comment: Your second (subjunctive) version is significantly more formal/dated, so you'd probably be well-advised to stick with the first one.

Comment: Both sound good to me.

Comment: @Andrew: What are you? A die-hard subjunctivist? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I'm American and easily impressed by anything that sounds remotely like posh British   :)

Comment: (I think anyone who's okay with asking whether something is "okay" probably *doesn't* want to get bogged down with things like the subjunctive in contexts like this! :)

Comment: Related, if not actual dups: [The condition that {something} be {something}](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114265/) and [Why is it 'come' and not 'comes' in 'it is important that he come…'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/72518/)

Comment: I don't generally like questions that ask, "Is this okay?" because the answer is generally, "Sure, it's okay." In this case, though, I'll point out that it reads a little awkward to me, and I'd prefer seeing something like: "Her condition was **so grave** that he was not allowed into her house."

Comment: @Andrew Posh BrE would be more "Her condition was *such* that *it would not be advisable* he be allowed in her house.:  ;-)

Comment: @Peter - I was thinking about mentioning "such that" – I'm glad you did.

Comment: I think the datedness of #2 may have to do with which side of the Atlantic you're on, and whether you tend to read the kind of texts where it's used, or not.  It strikes me as formal, not dated.

Comment: Guys, I think the context is that this is a *demand* or *requirement* of hers. It's not a medical condition, AFAIK.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, agreed.  And, that being the case, #2 seems better to me.  Cleaner, more succinct.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - Ohhhh! **That** kind of condition. (I wish the OP had explained that. I swear, sometimes questions get asked around here as if we charge by the word or something.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the context of the question is that she is making a *demand*, as in

> A condition of the agreement is that he not be allowed within 150
>   feet of the house.

then the subjunctive is fine. It is more formal than the modal "should not be", however, if the context demands formality (as an agreement would), the subjunctive is not dated or old-fashioned but quite common.

Comment: However, in case it was a medical condition, you could write "Her condition was *such* that he should not be allowed into her house." from the POV of a third-party.

Comment: @user3169: She could also be having a bad hair day. Or she could be naked.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.  The second example is in the present subjunctive and is more formal, but both are grammatically correct.  I like the subjunctive form you give though and I would probably use it most of the time; however that's just my choice.